# Knockout application becomes unresponsive

Tags: asp.net, knockout.js, iis-7.5

I have an hybrid asp.net MVC / knockout js application. After short period of moderate, concurrent use the knockout portion of application becomes unresponsive and the only way to set it back to normal operational mode is to recycle IISapp pool. As a temp workaround a set recycle value on app pool to 20 min and of course that change has its own set of issues.

Due to amount of data returned from the server I did have add an entry to web.config setting `maxJsonLength` to 2147483644.

Comment: If recycling the app pool temporary resolves the issue, it just means that the problem doesn't have anything to do with knockout on the client side. It is very likely that, it has to do with ajax calls to the server and I would focus on looking to those calls and see if there is anything that can be optimized on the server side.

Comment: @Sam, that make sense, but if it was a purely ajax calls, wouldn't navigating away or reopening the browser fix the problem?

Comment: Hmmm interesting .. have you had a chance to view the network load (using chrome developer tools) caused by client side scripts? it would be great to see a screenshot of that to fully understand the root cause here. using that we can see if the lag is due to a request or heavy processing on the browser by Knockout.

Comment: @Sam the screenshot is below

Comment: I don't see any AJAX calls, have you taken this screenshot when the knockout section of the site was unresponsive?

Comment: Ok, here's another screenshot with AJAX request. Sorry about the previous one, I knew it didn't look right. The new screenshot is taken while application is in normal operational state.It is a little difficult to set the app to unresponsive state on command.

Comment: I can tell you for a fact that If you are loading the entire 378 KB JSON data to knockout and trying to bind and show all of it on the UI you will definitely experience some latency ... having said that, the screenshot doesn't show any lag when making the server calls and that leads me to one more clarification question. when the page is unresponsive, did you try to open the Url on a different browser and see if it is still unresponsive?

Comment: Yes I can go to any computer on a network and if attempt to navigate to the page that uses knockout application hangs and eventually gives me a script error. That said, if I reopen the browser and navigate to the part of application that doesn't use Knockout than the pages load as they should.

Answer (score 0):

[Updated screenshot of ajax request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6GXZn.png)